# Get nearest centroid using Thrust library? (K-Means)

Tags: c++, cuda, k-means, thrust

I already finished computing the distances and stored in a thrust vector, for instance, I have 2 centroids and 5 datapoints and the way I computed the distances was that for each centroid I computed the distances with the 5 datapoints first and stored in the array and later with the other centroid in a 1d array in distances, just like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < centroids.size(); ++i)
{
    computeDistance(Data, distances, centroids[i], nDataPoints, nDimensions);
}
```

Resulting in a vector 1d, for instance:

```
DistancesValues = {10, 15, 20, 12, 10, 5, 17, 22, 8, 7}

DatapointsIndex = {1, 2,  3,   4,  5,  1,  2,  3, 4, 5}
```

Where the first 5 values represent centroid 1 and other 5 values centroid 2.

What I would like to know if there is a thrust function in which I can store the count in another array of the minimum values for each centroid?

Comparing the values of each index, Result should  be:

```
Counts = {2, 3}
```

where:

```
CountOfCentroid 1 = 2       
CountOfCentroid 2 = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:

1. Create an additional centroid index vector:

   ```
   DistancesValues = {10, 15, 20, 12, 10, 5, 17, 22,  8, 7}
   DatapointsIndex = {1,   2,  3,  4,  5, 1,  2,  3,  4, 5}
   CentroidIndex   = {1,   1,  1,  1,  1, 2,  2,  2,  2, 2}
   ```
2. Now do a sort_by_key, using `DatapointsIndex` as the keys, and the other two vectors zipped together as the values.  This has the effect rearranging all 3 vectors so that the `DatapointsIndex` has like indices grouped together:

   ```
   DatapointsIndex = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5}
   ```

   (and the other 2 vectors are correspondingly rearranged).
3. Now do a reduce_by_key.  If we choose the `thrust::minimum` operator, we get a reduction that effectively chooses the minimum value in a group (rather than summing the values in a group).  reduce_by_key means that a reduction of this type is done on each consecutive group of like keys.  So we will once again use the `DatapointsIndex` as our key vector, and the other two vectors zipped together as our value vector. Most of the output of reduce_by_key we don't care about, except for the results vector that emanates from the `CentroidIndex` vector.  By counting centroid indices in this results vector, we can get the desired output.

Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t428.cu
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/discard_iterator.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_POINTS 5
#define NUM_CENTROID 2
#define DSIZE (NUM_POINTS*NUM_CENTROID)

int main(){

  int DistancesValues[DSIZE] = {10, 15, 20, 12, 10, 5, 17, 22, 8, 7};
  int DatapointsIndex[DSIZE] = {1, 2,  3,   4,  5,  1,  2,  3, 4, 5};
  int CentroidIndex[DSIZE]   = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

  thrust::device_vector<int> DV(DistancesValues, DistancesValues + DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> DI(DatapointsIndex, DatapointsIndex + DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> CI(CentroidIndex, CentroidIndex + DSIZE);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Ra(NUM_POINTS);
  thrust::device_vector<int> Rb(NUM_POINTS);

  thrust::sort_by_key(DI.begin(), DI.end(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(DV.begin(), CI.begin())));
  thrust::reduce_by_key(DI.begin(), DI.end(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(DV.begin(), CI.begin())), thrust::make_discard_iterator(), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(Ra.begin(), Rb.begin())), thrust::equal_to<int>(), thrust::minimum<thrust::tuple<int, int> >());
  printf("CountOfCentroid 1 = %d\n", thrust::count(Rb.begin(), Rb.end(), 1));
  printf("CountOfCentroid 2 = %d\n", thrust::count(Rb.begin(), Rb.end(), 2));

  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t428 t428.cu
$ ./t428
CountOfCentroid 1 = 2
CountOfCentroid 2 = 3
$
```

As Eric points out in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698969/cuda-thrust-find-index-of-minimum-value-among-multiple-vectors) (your question is almost a duplicate of that one), the `sort_by_key` is probably unnecessary.  The reordering of this data follows a regular pattern, so we don't need to harness the complexity of sort, and can therefore re-order the data with clever use of iterators. Under those circumstances, it may be possible to do the entire operation (approximately) with a single call to `reduce_by_key`.

Comment: Amazing Robert! Thanks a lot! I will also check Eric's answer and see if I can do the entire operation with Reduce_by_keys.